# iPhone Safari browser not binding the div click event

Tags: javascript, iphone, dom-events, mobile-safari

I have a div element which did not had the CSS setting of `cursor:pointer`. I wanted to bind a JS `click` event on that  div but JS was not listening to the `click` event on the div.

This setting works well for all browsers including Safari, mobile emulator on Safari,
Android, Galaxy Tab.

It just doesn't seems to be working for iPhone.

When I added the `cursor:pointer` on the div, it started to work. Can anybody explain me what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that CLICK handler is not called at all then you can try to use touch events like "touchstart" or "touchend" because on touch devices you don't have mouse pointer so you can't "click".